# In R. Change specific character of columnB lead by what is present in another column

Tags: r, string, dataframe, for-loop, replace

My df:

```
1               2    3   4
AASCAVDITK      A    D   1
ADEAATDTINR     D    S   2
AIADGSLLDFLR    L    P   8
```

I want to change the letters of column 2 for the letters of column 3, the position of the letter is given by column 4.

I have tried to do a For statement with no success

Comment: Welcome to SO. please make your question reproducible by including your data as a dataframe object or use dput(df). Also include how you want the output to look like. It is also helpful if you include your code so that you can show what you have tried so we can see where the code breaks down so the community can help you. Have a look at this link [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `substr` like below

```
df$X5 <- `substr<-`(df$X1,df$X4,df$X4,df$X3)
```

or

```
df$X5 <- apply(df,1,function(x) {substr(x[1],x[4],x[4])<-x[3];x[1]})
```

which gives

```
> df
            X1 X2 X3 X4           X5
1   AASCAVDITK  A  D  1   DASCAVDITK
2  ADEAATDTINR  D  S  2  ASEAATDTINR
3 AIADGSLLDFLR  L  P  8 AIADGSLPDFLR
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c("AASCAVDITK", "ADEAATDTINR", "AIADGSLLDFLR"
), X2 = c("A", "D", "L"), X3 = c("D", "S", "P"), X4 = c(1L, 2L,
8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```